# Existence of exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M = \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i$ where $M_i$'s are $A$-modules for some commutative ring $A$. Show that $M$ is flat $\iff$ each $M_i$ is flat.

Atiyah says that a module $M$ is flat if for any exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow N' \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow N'' \longrightarrow 0$$  the tensored sequence $$0 \longrightarrow N' \otimes M \longrightarrow N \otimes M \longrightarrow N'' \otimes M \longrightarrow 0$$ is exact.

Now since for the tensor product we have that $$ N \otimes (M_1 \oplus M_2 \oplus \dots)= (N \otimes M_1) \oplus (N \otimes M_2) \oplus \dots$$ and thus $$0 \longrightarrow N' \otimes M \longrightarrow N \otimes M \longrightarrow N'' \otimes M \longrightarrow 0$$ is exact if and only if $$0 \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} (N' \otimes M_i) \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} (N \otimes M_i) \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} (N'' \otimes M_i)\longrightarrow 0$$ is exact. This sequence is exact if and only if each $M_i$ is exact so I think that would conclude the proof.

My question is that how can I guarantee that there exists any exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow N' \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow N'' \longrightarrow 0$$ to even begin with? These seem to be pulled out of some kind of magic hat...

Comment: If no exact sequences exist, then all modules are vacuously flat. But of course, short exact sequences exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that it technically doesn't matter if such a sequence exists or not. The definition is "for any exact sequence etc.", so if there exists no such sequence, then the definition is always valid, and every module is flat. It's not very interesting, but there is no logical issue.

Fortunately there are a lot of exact sequences. Just take any module $N$, and any submodule $N'\subset N$, and then you get an exact sequence
$$0\to N'\to N\to N/N'\to 0$$
using the canonical injection morphism $N'\to N$ and projection morphism $N\to N/N'$. Actually every short exact sequence looks like that up to a natural isomorphism. For a stupid example, you can take $N=N'=0$. For less stupid examples, you may take $N$ to be free, and $N'$ a submodule generated by some random choice of generators in $N$.